# How can I check if a TextBox value format is like 28-87222?

Tags: vba

I want a TextBox value's format to be like Ex: 28-87222

My code.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

     If Not Format(TextBox3.Text, "00" - "00000") Then
        staffLabel.Caption = "Staff ID is invalid."
        TextBox3.SetFocus
    Else
        staffLabel.Caption = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Think about [exactly what](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/minus-operator) you are passing as the second argument to [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications), and why you are treating its return value as `Boolean`.

Comment: @Min Ko Ko check the answer that I provided you down and let me know if it works

Comment: If it's solved don't forget to vote that it's solved

Comment: sry bro.I didn't know about that before.But i will for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 If Not (TextBox3.Text like "##-#####") Then
    staffLabel.Caption = "Staff ID is invalid."
    TextBox3.SetFocus
Else
    staffLabel.Caption = ""
End If
```

Comment: Would that work if the input was A1-B2C3D? The OP wants the characters to be all digits.

Comment: he sais he wants to validate a format like " 28-87222", so he wants 2 digit followed by - and by 5 digits....where did you see him asking for A1-B2C3D ? the answer I gave me validate something like  28-87222 not A1-B2C3D

Comment: It was an honest question i.e. does your code allow non-digits as valid entries. If not then I agree your code works.

Comment: The # means any number between (0-9)....if you want caracters you should replace the # by ? or * based on what you need, but the # means digit

Comment: It works.Thank bro.Thank all of you.I appreciate and respect all of your comments.

Comment: I want to ask again bro.Above this code, TextBox.SetFocus didn't work.I want like that if user didn't fill staff id field and click tab to another filed.Then, i will show validation error and I want to move my mouse focus back to staff id field.but it didn't work.How can i fix that bro?

Comment: the problem of setfocus has nothing to do with your question about format, and it's hard to help you, if you don't provide more information...can you try to put your code in the event TextBox1_AfterUpdate() and see if it works ? and don't forget to tag the answer if it fits you as resolved by hitting the check under the question

Comment: @MinKoKo Did your setfocus worked ? did you try the AfterUpdate event ? If not try to provide more details about your code and form etc..to try to help you

Comment: I tried bro but it didn't work.I will explain my problem bro.Ex: in my userform, i have 2 textboxs date and name to check validation.When i opened userform, date field has focus.I do nothing in it and click tab.It focus to name field and show error message date is invalid.It's ok.I catch that with exit event.Then, i focus back to date field to input data.There ' s my problem."Name is invalid" error message showed.I want to do really is if date field have no input data.Tab key from my keyboard must not work,error message must show for it and focus must just have in date field.

Comment: Plz give me some advise if you can.I'll appreciate it.Private Sub TextBox1_Exit

     If Not IsDate(TextBox1) Then
     
            dateLabel.Caption = "Date is invalid."
            TextBox1.SetFocus
            
     Else
            dateLabel.Caption = ""
     End If
     
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Exit
    
    If Trim(TextBox2.Value) = "" Or IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then
        nameLabel.Caption = "Name is invalid."
        TextBox2.SetFocus
    Else
        nameLabel.Caption = ""
    End If
    
End Sub

Comment: Can you open a new question about the setfocus issue with code and print screen to be able to help ? what is the error that you got ? and why you do use IsDate(TextBox1) ? it should be IsDate(TextBox1.Text)

Answer (score 0):

`Format()` returns a Variant or a String. In your case, in the condition, a boolean is needed. The Variant or the String could be transferred to a boolean, but this would almost always return `True` - [Format Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications)

In general, to make sure that the value is formatted as you like it, make the formatter in the properties of the `Textbox()`, and not in the code.

**If you are sure, you want to do it in the code**, then compare the two values - the formatted one and the must-be-formatted one:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print checkFormat("1234-23", "####-##")   'True
    Debug.Print checkFormat("1234-523", "####-##")  'False

End Sub

Public Function checkFormat(initialValue As String, neededFormat As String) As Boolean
    checkFormat = CBool(initialValue Like neededFormat)
End Function
```

Comment: I want to ask again bro.Above this code, TextBox.SetFocus didn't work.I want like that if user didn't fill staff id field and click tab to another filed.Then, i will show validation error and I want to move my mouse focus back to staff id field.but it didn't work.How can i fix that bro?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regex` and put it in a function:

```
Function IsValidStaffIdNumber(staffId As String)
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

    regex.Pattern = "[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"

    Debug.Print regex.Test(staffId)
End Function

Sub Test()
    IsValidStaffIdNumber ("11-11111")   '~~> TRUE
    IsValidStaffIdNumber ("1-11111")    '~~> FALSE
    IsValidStaffIdNumber ("11-1111")    '~~> FALSE
    IsValidStaffIdNumber ("111-11111")  '~~> FALSE
    IsValidStaffIdNumber ("1A-1B2Cd")   '~~> FALSE
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to ask again bro.Above this code, TextBox.SetFocus didn't work.I want like that if user didn't fill staff id field and click tab to another filed.Then, i will show validation error and I want to move my mouse focus back to staff id field.but it didn't work.How can i fix that bro?